# textbox validation on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on simple website making a textbox and a button. while clicking on button error should be given that "textbox value can't be empty". i tried from many sites but my issue is not yet resolved. one important thing to mention this button and textbox is not enclosed in a form.

```
<input id="AccountText" type="text" name="AccountText" 
       class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required=''/>

<input id="AddAccount" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"  />
```

i have already tried controltovalidation but it is also not working for me.

Comment: "required" is used to validate textbox..

Comment: what do the tags [tag:c#], [tag:visual-studio] and [tag:asp.net] have to do with the question being asked?  None one of them are seemingly important to the code snippet posted.

Comment: @Kritner [`ControlToValidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property of ASP.Net validation controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Should help you get started.

**HTML**

```
<input id="AccountText" type="text" name="AccountText" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required=''/>

//submit button
<input class="button" type="submit" value="submit">
```

**JQUERY**

The basics: When the user clicks the submit button (using the `.click()` function) jquery checks whether the input value is empty (using `.val()` to get the value of the input.) If it is empty a message appears (using `alert()`) prompting the user to complete the field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
        if ($('#AccountText').val() == ""){
            alert('Please complete the field');
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/mfbaxkfp/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<input id="AccountText" type="text" name="AccountText" 
       class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required=''/>

<input id="AddAccount" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"  />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#AddAccount').click(function() {
        if (!$.trim($('#AccountText').val())) {
            alert("textbox value can't be empty");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Web Forms, you could make use of [ASP.Net validation controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx). Your markup will look something like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AccountText" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AccountTextValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="AccountText"
    Text="Textbox value can't be empty"
    />

<asp:Button ID="AddAccount" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Jquery Reference :**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<input id="AccountText" type="text" name="AccountText" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required='' />
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#AddAccount').click(function () {

    var inVal = $("#AccountText").val();

    if (inVal.length == 0) {
        alert("textbox value can't be empty");
        $("#AccountText").focus();
    }
});
```

});

**Demo :** [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeeshmenoth/m36pjLpr/)

Comment: i do not want to use alert. any other suggestion for example label , how can we use label to show the message???

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try one of the following:

1) make required='true'
2) If the textbox have some specific about what type of text to be entered, you can also put the regex pattern.
3) You can use this in your script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#AddAccount').click(function() {
            if (!$.trim($('#AccountText').val())) {
                alert("Please enter the text");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```